# Anyone been able to use Angular 4 Quickstart with Visual Studio 2015?

Tags: asp.net, angularjs, visual-studio

The current Angular Quickstart here: https://github.com/angular/quickstart now puts the index.html and related files under an src folder.

When trying to run the code in Visual Studio 2015 as an asp.net 4.x (not core) project with F5, it can't find the files in the src folder. It works using browser-sync  (with npm run) because the bs-config file redefines the base path. Is there anything similar to get the F5 experience to work?

Comment: When did angular 4 come out!!

Comment: It came out on Thursday. http://angularjs.blogspot.com/2017/03/angular-400-now-available.html

Answer (score 2):

Visual Studio Code is far more better for Angular 4 then Visual Studio 2015( accurately,Visual Studio 2017  as you cannot download Visual Studio 2015 community but 2017 now)
Just in case you wanta asp.netcode with angular 4, here is example:
https://github.com/Longfld/ASPNETCoreAngular4

Comment: Thank you for your post ... and I agree. But there are devs that want to (or have to) use Visual Studio 2015/17. I'm working with the Angular docs team trying to put together instructions for this scenario and am hoping for a solution that works. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Please see [this](https://github.com/mortezadalil/angular4-Mvc5) repo base on angular quickstart.
I hope to be useful for you.

`https://github.com/mortezadalil/angular4-Mvc5`